# Можно ли установить промежутки срабатывания $(window).scroll(function() {})

Tags: javascript, jquery

При скролле, получаю значение отступа от верха докумена, и ставлю условие, если значение больше 700 то скрываю логотип который висит фиксированный. 
   $(window).scroll(function() {

```
            var scroll_1 = $(this).scrollTop();

            console.log(scroll_1);
            if(scroll_1 >= 700){
                $('.logo').css('opacity','0');

            }else{
                $('.logo').css('opacity','1');
            };
            console.log($('.logo').css('opacity'));

        });
```

Но если я скролю очень быстро, ползунком, .scroll отрабатывает поздно и логотип отображается там где не нужно. Для того чтобы наглядно показать я записал console.log для значения css opacity и значения .scrollTop.
у меня получается ,что есть промежуток значений .scrollTop() от 628 до 1348 на картинке, в который .scroll не срабатывает. То есть условие должно сработать на 700, а срабатывает аж на 1348. Можно ли как то установить значение срабатывания .scroll?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал сделать через IntersectionObserver, вывожу в консоли значение .scrollTop от window и значение css opacity:

```
const imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, imgObserver) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                if(entry.isIntersecting) {
                    $('.logo').css('opacity','0');
                    console.log('Opacity 0');
                     scroll_null = $(window).scrollTop();
                     console.log(scroll_null);
                }else{
                    $('.logo').css('opacity','1');
                    console.log('Opacity 1');
                     scroll_null = $(window).scrollTop();
                     console.log(scroll_null);
                }
            })
        });
        imageObserver.observe(document.querySelector('div.main-ck11-text'));
```

При медленном скроле срабатывает на .scrollTop() =206
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если скролить быстро ползунком срабатывает на .scrollTop()=1260

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не лучше будет использовать `Intersection Observe`????

Comment: Нет, так управлять скроллом нельзя.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko почему scroll когда я скролю до конца документа срабатывает несколько раз в рандомных местах?

Comment: @MoloF использовал Intersection Observe, проблема осталась, срабатывает слишком поздно при прокрутке ползунком быстрой или быстро колесом мыши

Comment: Это касается не только скролла, так сделано для экономии ресурсов. У вас не будет вызываться событие скролл на скролл каждого пикселя и управлять этим нельзя.

Comment: @MoloF то же самое и для Intersection Observe, логотип скрывается  поздно при быстром скролле. Есть какие то варианты скрывать логотип именно на расстоянии 700px от верха страницы, не используя .scroll| или  Intersection Observe? Я не думаю что я первый столкнулся с этим, возможно решение намного проще

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko для Intersection Observe  то же самое, для этого метода тоже стоят ограничения из-за большого потребления ресурсов?

Comment: Да, именно так. Можете попробовать решить через requestAnimationFrame, в обработчике будете узнавать scrollTop и делать вашу логику. Только учтите, этот колбек будет вызываться много раз в секунду, не пишите тяжелые операции в него.