# Скрывать элемент , если экран браузера на высоте 700 px от верха страницы, не используя .scroll или IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Скрывать элемент , если экран браузера на высоте 700 px от верха страницы, не используя .scroll или IntersectionObserver. Если использую .scroll или IntersectionObserver, то при быстром скролле скрипт срабатывает не на 700px а на 1260 px
[Можно ли установить промежутки срабатывания $(window).scroll(function() {})](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138275/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-window-scrollfunction)

Comment: Не надо создавать дулбикаты вопросов.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko это не дубликат, первый вопрос про промежуток срабатывания .scroll() данный вопрос про реализацию функционала другим способом

Comment: Понятно, с использованием requestAnimationFrame мне удалось добиться только точности в 100 пикселей. Похоже, никак нельзя сделать.